# MS Clarity has the ability to turn off query string parameters, but is there a way to turn off MVC routing parameters?

Tags: ms-clarity

You can set MS Clarity to ignore query string parameters such as https://www.mytest.com/home?id=1, but is it possible to set it to ignore the id at the end of an MVC url such as https://www.mytest.com/home/1 ?
We use this a lot on some of our web apps and if we can't set it to ignore that, the data is much less useful.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not have a method to ignore the IDs that are part of the URL.